# vb.net displaying results in a secondary form using a sub procedure no button click

Tags: vb.net, forms

I am a student trying to figure out load a form with the values coming back from a subprocedure. Every example that I find is linked to a button click event so I am having difficulty figuring out the parameters for the return. I think that I have all of the code correct for my program with the exception of the part with ** around it.

```
    Private Sub Results_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, **ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult**)

    DisplayNumbers()
    ShowResults()
```

Comment: No, you cannot change the argument types of an event.  Very unclear what you are trying to do, the code makes no sense.  Initialize a form by adding a constructor (Sub New) that takes arguments.

Comment: Don't get exactly what you are trying to do here. You certainly cand call that from a standard button click event.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a result from a method, use a `Function` in VB.

```
Private Function Square (ByVal x As Double) As Double
    Return x * x
End Function
```

You can then call it with

```
Dim result As Double = Square(7.5)
```

Or in your form

```
ResultTextBox.Text = Square(CDbl(ValueTextBox.Text)).ToString()
```

---

Another possibility is to pass an object to a `Sub` that you "fill" with  results

```
Public Sub FillMyForm(ByVal frm As MyForm)
    frm.FirstNameTextBox.Text = "John"
    frm.LastNameTextBox.Text = "Doe"
End Sub
```

If this `Sub` was defined in a module just call it like this in your form

```
 FillMyForm(Me)
```